# Как в java по нажатию кнопки открыть изображение в новом окне?

Tags: java, swing

Есть некая кнопка <kbd>показать изображение</kbd>. Каким образом можно при нажатии этой кнопки открыть изображение в окне просмотрщика изображений *Windows*, если абсолютный путь изображения известен?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [java.awt.Desktop](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0579.html).

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class Test2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  File f = new File("c:\\temp\\test.bmp");
  Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
  dt.open(f);
  System.out.println("Done.");
 }
}
```

`Desktop.getDesktop().open()` вызывает программу по умолчанию для данного типа файлов. Так-же можно вызвать браузер по умолчанию для открытия ссылки или стандартный почтовый клиент и т.д.